# Why is the gradient of Energy vs. wavenumber(k) zero at the edge of Brillouin zones?

Tags: semiconductors, theory, physics

My question relates to semiconductor physics. The relationship between energy *E* and wavenumber *k* for the [Kronig-Penny model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_one-dimensional_lattice#Kronig.E2.80.93Penney_model) looks like this, where *a* is the period of the potential function:

[image]

I am referring to a statement made in the book *Advanced Semiconductor Fundamentals, 2nd Edition by Robert F. Pierret*, page 61. In reference to the E-k diagram of the Kronig-Penney model it says:

> ...the energy band slope *dE/dk* is zero at the k-zone boundaries.

and referring to the gradient:

> This is a feature common to all *E-k* plots, even those characterizing real materials.

Why is the gradient zero at the k-zone boundaries (i.e. edges of Brillouin zones)? What does it signify?

Answer (score 1):

The x axis on the plot is proportional to momentum.  The k-zone boundary in your diagram, is the point with zero momentum (no *net* motion of a carrier.);  So, in the plot you show, that's why it's the minimum point as all other points have a net motion greater than it. You will notice, that the graph is symmetrical about the k=0 point in the kronig-penny model.  The gradient is zero because of that symmetry. From basic calculus, when you take the derivative of a function, it is always zero at an extremium.

Answer (score 1):

A detailed mathematical analysis of Kronig-Penney model yields a mathematical equation comprising of two parameters k and q.

$$\cos(qa)+\frac{mg}{{\hslash}^2 q \sin(qa)} = \cos(ka)$$ where  $$q = \sqrt{\frac{2mE}{\hslash}}$$ q is the parameter involved the solution of wavefunction of Schrodinger equation.

Here the k parameter denotes the crystal momentum not the electron momentum.
Now, not going into detailed math, in this model (1-D), the Bragg law of reflecetion must be restated. It is essential to note this law in order to explain why the dE/dk is 0 at top of the curve and the negative differential effective mass of electron.

Bragg law: wavelength - w; angle - t;

$$w = 2a\sin{t}$$

Note 1-D model, so only back scattering so t = 90 degrees.

Also by de Broglie formula:

$$w = \frac{h}{p}$$

$$p=\hslash q$$

$$\hslash=2 \pi h$$

On solving above equations we get \$q=\frac{n \pi}{a}\$. For lowest degree, n=1. So \$q=\frac{\pi}{a}\$, Bragg reflection takes place even when the k vector is in the opposite direction.

What this results in is a standing wave due to the creation of two waves in two directions (Bloch wave functions). dE/dk is a measure of group velocity and this being zero implies there is a presence of standing wave at Bragg Reflection points